# Starting iterrows() loop on a particular index

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I'm using `iterrows()` to do calculations on a dataset that uses a timestamp as its index.  See below as an example:

```
>>> aapl.head()
Date        Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close                                                        
1980-12-12  28.75  28.88  28.75  28.75  16751200       3.15
1980-12-15  27.38  27.38  27.25  27.25   6281600       2.99
1980-12-16  25.38  25.38  25.25  25.25   3776000       2.77
1980-12-17  25.88  26.00  25.88  25.88   3087200       2.84
1980-12-18  26.62  26.75  26.62  26.62   2623200       2.92
```

I was planning on doing my calculation using `for index in aapl.iterrows()` but I'm only looking at values within a specific year and the dataset contains much more data than that.  How might I get my loop to start on a particular index value (namely timestamp in this case) and end on another?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you should show what you are planning on doing operations-wise. looping is generally **not** a good solution.

Comment: You should also be able to just create a subset of that dataframe using the methods here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#datetime-indexing

Answer (score 2):

Most python iteration functions have an optional start argument. DataFrames don't, but DataFrames are generally much easier to slice into. So I'd suggest slice then iterate:

```
for row, value in aapl.loc['1980-12-18':].iterrows():
    # do stuff.
```

What goes into `.loc` depends on what you want. You may even be able to use `.ix[<YEAR>]`, like `.ix['1990']`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That seems like a logical solution but I keep getting the following error:

`>>> for row, value in joined.loc['2012-12-18':].iterrows():
...     print row['Close_NCBC']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#119>", line 2, in <module>
    print row['Close_NCBC']
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Anything I might be overlooking?

Comment: Don't you want value['Close_NCBC'] ?

Comment: @user1827356 Thanks for the response.  Indeed I do; the script above was just to test the proposed solution for running the for-loop at a given starting point.  The error at hand comes from using the timestamp in the loop; the print command doesn't appear be the issue.